# how to show specific field of a form for 'create' and 'edit' action - Symfony3

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a simple `FormType` attached to an entity called `media` which I rendered in my view.
I have a `newAction` that lets me create my object, and a `editAction` that lets me edit it with my same form in my controller.
However I don't want some field appears in my `edit` view` as I already entered them when I created it.

But even though I use `form_row` to specifically render my form line by line, when I add the `form_end` at the end, it renders all my fields, even the ones I didn't call.

**My FormType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class'          => null,
            'label'               => "Add an image"
        ))
        ->add('context', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label'               => 'image section',
            'choices' => array(
                'header' => 'header',
                'middle' => 'middle',
            )
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label'               => "Add"
        ));
}
```

**My view**

```
{{ form_start(editForm) }}
{{ form_row(editForm.name) }}
{{ form_row(editForm.save) }}
{{ form_end(editForm) }}
```

But even if I use the form rows, it actually shows my `context` field in the view, which I didn't call.
So I tried some hack to get around it.

this one worked but when I click on `submit` form, it shows me an error that `context` field cannot be null, so this doesn't do the trick

```
{% do editForm.context.setRendered %}
```

And I found a way to do it with jQuery to hide the form like this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#media_context").parent().hide();
        });
    </script>
```

the jQuery works and hide my row in my form. But I was wondering if I could do it without using jQuery and be able to render only specific field of my form in my view?

Comment: You have to add `'required' => false` to `context` field in form builder if you want submit form without this field.

Comment: hi @malcolm, thanks for answering but your proposition doesn't work, the field appears even when I add the `required` :(

Comment: Because `form_end` add all missing fields. My comment was about the error "field cannot be null". You can now use `{% do editForm.context.setRendered %}`.

Comment: Ha I see ! so how can I render a form with specific field without rendering some of them like in my question? How can I do that? I still need the `form_start` and `form_end` right? but if its rendering all fields automatically, what is the point to have a `form_row` then? By the way your solution still doesn't work, I have this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'context' cannot be null` even after added `required => false`

Comment: Also consider: "Best Practice: Add buttons in the templates, not in the form classes or the controllers." http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration

Comment: @malcolm thanks for the link, I will check that for my submit button. rather having in the form I will add it to my view. But I still have my problem about generating specific field from the form :(

Comment: You have to set default value for you entity field dn allow null values http://stackoverflow.com/a/9986331/3675759

Comment: The point to have `form_row` is that you can rearrange or style with HTML your form field, and later `form_end` displays all the rest fields. You can ommit `form_end` and display the crsf token and submit widget like the rest of fields.

Comment: I tried adding the value `null` to my entity. it worked but didn't display my image properly. I guess there is some trouble with that. so I can do that by omitting writing form_end that is all? what about the crsf token? should I add it that too?

Comment: I didn't thought that this was complicated to solve :/..... nobody have a clue on how to not show a specific field from a form? I didn't get the crsf token

Comment: Cannot understand you, you need that field in your entity, but you don't want that field to appear inside form?

Comment: @malcolm yes. Actually I have a controller that calls this form to be able to `create` and `edit` so when I want to create my form i want to choose the `context` but when I edit it, i should not see the `context` as it has already been given. That is why I try to hide this field when I edit, but keep it when I create a new entry

Comment: Why go through all this hassle?  Just make two forms and be done with it.

Comment: @cerad I never knew I could make two form for one entity. I don't have all knowledge

Comment: Can't begin to tell you how many times I have banged my ahead against a wall trying to solve a "complex" problem only to have a simple solution staring at me right in the face.

Comment: @cera haha yeah, it feels exactly like that.I feel you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Symfony 2, you could remove some fields from the builder when editing your entity. Your edit form must `extends` your create form in Symfony 2.

I think you can do the same in Symfony 3, try something like :

```
class EditType extends CreateType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->remove('context') //remove the fields that no longer needed
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        /...
    }
}
```

You don't need to change `CreateType`

```
class Createtype extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
        ->add('name', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class'          => null,
            'label'               => "Add an image"
        ))
        ->add('context', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label'               => 'image section',
            'choices' => array(
                'header' => 'header',
                'middle' => 'middle',
            )
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label'               => "Add"
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mickedv if i understand correctly your solution. It means that in my AppBundle/Form I need to have a folder called `MediaType` for my media entity. In this folder I have `CreateType` and `EditType` ? I currently only have only one form just like in my question. So I need to have 2 forms? one for creating and one for editing?

Comment: Hi @crisscross, instead of creating a workaround with javascript `$("#media_context").parent().hide();`, I will recommend creating two forms. It's clean and if you want to remove another form in the future it will be very simple. Your code will be more maintainable this way

Comment: @mickedv what you propose me sounds like a great solution! :) I will try it right away! but your answer is incomplete. You see my formType in my question right? it is the one I use currently. so what should I put in createType and EditType then? can you update your answer because I still don't know where to put the `remove` option

Comment: Should I put them in a folder named after my entity?

Comment: In Symfony 2, entity is in `/entity` folder and forms in `/form` folder. I don't know about Symfony 3 but just follow the convention. Where did you put your formtypes ?

Comment: I putted my FormTypes in the Form folder in the AppBundle.I guess its pretty similar to symfony 2 (im refactoring my code to suit your answer at this moment)

Comment: I have a new error `Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Services\FileUploader::upload() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, null given, called in /var/www/html/FoodAndYou_V2/src/AdminBundle/Controller/MediaController.php on line 61` he doesn't like my double form. I wonder what is this new issue :/

Comment: Do you attribute the correct form to the correct action ? createAction: `$form =$this->createForm(new CreateType(), $entity);` and EditAction: `$form = $this->createForm(new EditType(), $entity);`. Also, line 61 is in create or edit action ?

Comment: I have this for createAction `$form = $this->createForm(MediaType\CreateType::class, $media);` and this for editAction `$editForm = $this->createForm(MediaType\EditType::class, $media)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138459/discussion-between-mickdev-and-criss-cross).

Answer (score 3):

From the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html):

This helper (form_end) also outputs form_rest() unless you set render_rest to false.

form_rest(view, variables)

This renders all fields that have not yet been rendered for the given form.

```
{# don't render unrendered fields #}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found my solution before I could see your comment. But thank you for writing

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{{ form_start(editForm) }}
{{ form_row(editForm.name) }}
{{ form_row(editForm.save) }}
{{ form_end(editForm, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually found my solution with @mickdev, but thank you for writing